# ECS Splunk logs truncated with splunk-format raw

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, splunk

I'm having an `AWS ECS Cluster` and have configured it with `Splunk` logging and `splunk-format: raw` in task definition like below:

```
{
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "splunk",
    "secretOptions": [
      {
        "valueFrom": "myarn",
        "name": "splunk-token"
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "splunk-url": "my-splunk-url",
      "splunk-source": "my-splunk-source",
      "splunk-format": "raw"
    }
  }
}
```

All my dashboards in Splunk are expecting this format. The message are getting truncated at `4kb`. Changing the format to `inline` does not truncate the messages but using this new format would require alot of rework in the Splunk Dashboards.

Is there a way to get this to work with `splunk-format: raw` without having message getting truncated?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the channel size through environment variable SPLUNK_LOGGING_DRIVER_CHANNEL_SIZE configured in the task definition

4kb appears to be the default size according to the docs at
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/splunk/

[image]